# Ошибка "No fixture, test, or step context is active.", если в параметрах теста есть Func

Tags: allure

Ошибка "No fixture, test, or step context is active." падает, когда в TestCaseData передаю Func:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без Func проходит без ошибок. Подскажите, можно ли Allure подружить с Func?

Пример:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Allure.Attributes;
using NUnit.Allure.Core;

namespace /*ваш namespace*/;

[TestFixture]
[AllureNUnit]
[AllureSuite("Demo")]
public class Demo
{
    [AllureFeature("Demo test")]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(Cases))]
    public void CheckCases(Func<int, bool> getExpectedResult, int number)
    {
        getExpectedResult(number).Should().Be(number > 0);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Cases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(Builder.GetResult1, 1).SetName("01 Demo test"); 
            yield return new TestCaseData(Builder.GetResult2, -2).SetName("02 Demo test");
        }
    }
    
    [AllureFeature("Demo test")]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(Cases2))]
    public void CheckCases(int number)
    {
        Builder.GetResult1(number).Should().Be(number > 0);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Cases2
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(1).SetName("01 Demo test"); 
            yield return new TestCaseData(2).SetName("02 Demo test");
        }
    }
}

public static class Builder
{
    public static bool GetResult1(int number)
    {
        return number > 0;
    }
    
    public static bool GetResult2(int number)
    {
        return number < 0;
    }
}
```